# sort a table in jsp using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp, sorting

I am trying to sort a table in jsp. I used a jquery plugin called tableSorter to sort my table, but I haven't had any luck. This is my code. I am not sure where I am missing things. I am populating this table from MYSQL database.

This is my table sorter function that I am using to sort the table in the jsp.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tinysort.min.js"></script>

var aAsc = [];
function sortTable(nr) {
aAsc[nr] = aAsc[nr]=='asc'?'desc':'asc';
$('#records>tbody>tr').tsort('td:eq('+nr+')[abbr]',{order:aAsc[nr]});
}

<table ID="records" class="results" border="1" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><a href="javascript:sortTable(0)" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline; ">ID</a></th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>

 <logic:notEmpty property="results" name="finalResults" scope="page">
 <logic:iterate id="i" indexId="count" property="results" name="finalResults" scope="page">

  <%-- Logic for formatting the data from DB goes here--%>
 </logic:iterate>
 </logic:notEmpty>
```

I am using href here to sort my data. But href doesn't do anything when I click on it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You don't have up and down arrows in table (like in [docs demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Demo)) or what?

Comment: I am using href to sort the data. Upon clicking on it, the column sorts. I want to sort the individual columns rather than the whole table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class should be tablesorter

like : table ID="records" class="**tablesorter**" border="1" cellspacing="0"

Try This::

I have made one example please see this link, here Iám using `_jquery.tablesorter.min.js` let me know if this help.
[tableSorter Example](http://jsfiddle.net/santosanta/7nqdcqp4/1/)

Comment: I tried using tablesorter for class. It didn't help.

Comment: I have updated with example. Please check and let me know if that help

Comment: Yeah it worked. But I was able to sort the data in my first page only. I have about 20 pages and how do I use pagination here to sort my data.

Comment: in that case you can either do it on server side like adding Order by **name** or **date** or **Id** in you Select Query.

**OR**

Getting entire data in JSON and displaying 1-20 record during on load then remaining on the basis of **Next click event** you can display 20-40 records using this it will sort the entire column using above Example.

I would recommend you to user server side sorting because it will take lot of time to do on client side using JSON